# Why Won't This Render as JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I have a string variable, with this HTML code like so:

this.state.contents:

```
<p>This Handbook is designed to provide you with information about your employment at {this.props.clientName} and its affiliates and subsidiaries (referred to throughout this Handbook as “{this.props.clientName}” or the “Company”).</p>
```

I pass it to a child component like this:

```
<Policy key={filteredPolicy.id} id={filteredPolicy.id} contents={filteredPolicy.contents} clientName={this.state.client}/>
```

The child component is this:

```
<Card.Body className="content" >{this.props.contents}</Card.Body>
```

But in the component, it renders as the string and just shows all the HTML tags.  How do I get it to actually render correctly as HTML code? A second issue is the variables of `{this.props.clientName}` also do not show up... it just literally renders `{this.props.clientName}` as a string.  It all works correctly if I just do it as HTML.  But when I try to do it this way, no dice.

Comment: "It all works correctly if I just do it as HTML" if you mean JSX and it works, why not do it the React way? Which `this.props.clientName` are you attempting to "inject" into the tags? Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we may see what your code is doing and what exactly you are saving into `this.state.contents`. Keep in mind that it's generally an anti-pattern to store JSX into component state.

Comment: The reason is that React by default sanitizes and removes code from the JSX content as a security measure. There is a back door ( see the official react documentation ) but it is very important to know its security implications and how to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

While you can still use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to achieve it like this, it's [**not recommended**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
function Child({ data }) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}></div>;
}

const test = "test-data";

export default function App() {
  const [data] = useState(`<div>${test}</div>`); // note the ${} (template literal) here instead of {}, because this is a string, not React component
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Child data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lucy-x7cdy?file=/src/App.js)

Define a `renderData` function inside `Parent` component to render your html, pass it to `Child` as a prop, and call that `renderData` function here. You can use your state, props inside that `renderData` function as you want.

So the above example can be rewrite like this

```
function Child({ renderData }) {
  return <div>{renderData()}</div>;
}

const test = "test-data";

export default function App() {

  const renderData = () => {
    return (
      <div>{test}</div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Child renderData={renderData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-solomon-g66xe?file=/src/App.js)